# Arrays and type class-lifting (and dependent types?)

Tags: haskell, typeclass, dependent-type

Let say that the type `b` is an instance of `Monoid` and for a fixed indices range of `(v1,v2) :: (i,i)` with `i` belonging to the type class `Ix` I want to define the corresponding Data.Array type to be a Monoid as well. How can this be done? Here, `mempty` should be the Array with entries `mempty::b` and also `mappend` for arrays should be the `mappend`-operation component-wise.

(For instance if `i=(Int,Int)` the type `Data.Array i b` represents of all (2 dimensional) matricies with different sizes (and different ranges of the index). Only for fixed size such a `Monoid`-declaration makes sense. Actually, I am interested in the vector-space case instead of Monoids, but Monoid already shows the difficulty. I have only a vague idea about dependent type but this seems to be a prototypical example for a situation in which individual types corresponding to the only a subset of the range of one parameter would be useful.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A common way is to wrap a not-very-typed representation into a more typed one like this:

```
data Nat = Z | S Nat
newtype Vec (n :: Nat) a = Vec [a]
newtype Sized m (ns :: [Nat]) a = Sized { getArray :: Array (Vec m Int) a }
```

Here `ns` is a promoted (see [Giving Haskell a Promotion](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~sweirich/papers/tldi12.pdf)) phantom (see [Motivation behind Phantom Types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28247543/motivation-behind-phantom-types)) value — a list of sizes of dimensions and `m` is the length of this list (promoted and phantom as well). So any array under the `Sized` wrapper is assumed to be a multidimensional matrix with `ns` representing its dimensions. The `Monoid` instance then looks like this:

```
instance (SingI m, SingI ns, Monoid a) => Monoid (Sized m ns a) where
  mempty                      = listSized $ repeat mempty
  Sized as `mappend` Sized bs = listSized $ zipWith mappend (elems as) (elems bs)
```

That `SingI` stuff is from the [singletons](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons) library. Singletons allow to lift values to the type-level, so we can kinda emulate dependent types, and `SingI` allows to get lifted values back at the value level via the `fromSing` function. `listSized` is essentially `listArray`, but for arrays with statically known dimensions and hence it requires all those `SingI`s to be in scope. Here is its definition:

```
toInt :: Nat -> Int
toInt = go 0 where
  go !a  Z    = a
  go  a (S n) = go (1 + a) n

vecBounds :: forall m (ns :: [Nat]). (SingI m) => Sing ns -> (Vec m Int, Vec m Int)
vecBounds singNs = (Vec $ replicate m 0, Vec ns') where
    m   = toInt $ fromSing (sing :: Sing m)
    ns' = map (pred . toInt) $ fromSing singNs

listSized :: forall m (ns :: [Nat]) a. (SingI m, SingI ns) => [a] -> Sized m ns a
listSized = Sized . listArray (vecBounds (sing :: Sing ns))
```

`vecBounds` computes bounds for a given promoted list of sizes of dimensions. It returns a tuple which first component is the lowerest index which is always of the form `[0,0..0]` (there as many zeros as there are dimensions, i.e. `m`). The second component is the greatest index, so if you e.g. have a list of sizes of dimensions like `[2, 1, 3]` (represented as `[S (S Z), S Z, S (S (S Z))]`), then the maximum index is `[1, 0, 2]`.

It only remains to provide an `Ix` instance for `Vec n a` which is a direct generalization of [the product instances](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Arr.html#line-280):

```
instance Ix a => Ix (Vec n a) where
  range   (Vec ns, Vec ms)          = map Vec . sequence $ zipWith (curry range) ns ms
  index   (Vec ns, Vec ms) (Vec ps) = foldr (\(i, r) a -> i + r * a) 0 $
    zipWith3 (\n m p -> (index (n, m) p, rangeSize (n, m))) ns ms ps
  inRange (Vec ns, Vec ms) (Vec ps) = and $ zipWith3 (curry inRange) ns ms ps
```

And we can write some tests:

```
type M  = S (S (S Z))
type Ns = [S (S Z), S Z, S (S (S Z))]

arr1 :: Sized M Ns (Sum Int)
arr1 = listSized $ map Sum [5,3,6,7,1,4]

arr2 :: Sized M Ns (Sum Int)
arr2 = listSized $ map Sum [8,2,9,7,3,6]

main = mapM_ (print . getArray) $ [arr1, arr2, arr1 `mappend` arr2 `mappend` mempty]
```

This prints

```
array (Vec [0,0,0],Vec [1,0,2]) [(Vec [0,0,0],Sum {getSum = 5}),(Vec [0,0,1],Sum {getSum = 6}),(Vec [0,0,2],Sum {getSum = 1}),(Vec [1,0,0],Sum {getSum = 3}),(Vec [1,0,1],Sum {getSum = 7}),(Vec [1,0,2],Sum {getSum = 4})]
array (Vec [0,0,0],Vec [1,0,2]) [(Vec [0,0,0],Sum {getSum = 8}),(Vec [0,0,1],Sum {getSum = 9}),(Vec [0,0,2],Sum {getSum = 3}),(Vec [1,0,0],Sum {getSum = 2}),(Vec [1,0,1],Sum {getSum = 7}),(Vec [1,0,2],Sum {getSum = 6})]
array (Vec [0,0,0],Vec [1,0,2]) [(Vec [0,0,0],Sum {getSum = 13}),(Vec [0,0,1],Sum {getSum = 15}),(Vec [0,0,2],Sum {getSum = 4}),(Vec [1,0,0],Sum {getSum = 5}),(Vec [1,0,1],Sum {getSum = 14}),(Vec [1,0,2],Sum {getSum = 10})]
```

I.e. elements were summed pointwise as required. And if you accidentally try to sum arrays with different dimensions, you'll get a type error:

```
type Ns  = [S (S Z), S Z, S (S (S Z))]
type Ns' = [S (S (S Z)), S Z, S (S Z)]

arr1 :: Sized M Ns (Sum Int)
arr1 = listSized $ map Sum [5,3,6,7,1,4]

arr2 :: Sized M Ns' (Sum Int)
arr2 = listSized $ map Sum [8,2,9,7,3,6]

main = print . getArray $ arr1 `mappend` arr2

-- Couldn't match type 'S 'Z with 'Z …
-- Expected type: Sized M Ns (Sum Int)
--   Actual type: Sized M Ns' (Sum Int)
-- In the second argument of `mappend', namely `arr2'
-- In the first argument of `mappend', namely `arr1 `mappend` arr2'
```

[Full code](https://github.com/effectfully/random-stuff/blob/master/SizedMonoid.hs).

Comment: Wow :D! Thank you very much for your detail explanation and all your work!  To be honest, I'm afraid I have to read a lot before fully understanding the construction (I'm not familiar with neither phantoms nor promotions....). I've seen on your githut side that your are also using Agda. Can something like this be done with a dependent type language like Agda much more easily? Thanks a lot again!!!

Comment: @dmw64, you're welcome. As Agda has full dependent types, you don't need to lift values to the type level via singletons and can just use them directly there, so it saves you some boilerplate, but other than that you'd end up with something very similar (and AFAIK Agda doesn't have built-in arrays, so you'd have to use FFI and same phantom types).

Answer (score 3):

@user3237465's is a full and direct answer to your question about attaching static size information to `Array`s. But since you mentioned that you're quite new to dependent types, I wanted to give a simpler example of matrix addition which I feel may serve as a better introduction to the topic. Much of the below can be found (better-explained!) in [the *Hasochism* paper](https://personal.cis.strath.ac.uk/conor.mcbride/pub/hasochism.pdf).

As usual we have natural numbers, which GHC will automatically lift to the type level. Not only does the following `data` declaration define a type `Nat` and two value constructors `Z` and `S`, we also get a *kind* `Nat` and two *type* constructors `Z` and `S`.

```
data Nat = Z | S Nat

type One = S Z
type Two = S (S Z)
type Three = S (S (S Z))
```

I'm going to define the customary *vector* GADT, which is operationally a linked list with static knowledge of its length.

```
infixr 5 :>
data Vec n a where
    VNil :: Vec Z a
    (:>) :: a -> Vec n a -> Vec (S n) a
deriving instance Show a => Show (Vec n a)

instance Functor (Vec n) where
    fmap f VNil = VNil
    fmap f (x :> xs) = f x :> fmap f xs
```

Here are some example vectors.

```
v1 :: Vec Two String
v1 = "foo" :> "bar" :> VNil
v2 :: Vec Two String
v2 = "baz" :> "quux" :> VNil
v3 :: Vec One String
v3 = "nabble" :> VNil
```

We're going to need to do runtime analysis of type-level numbers. For example, we'd like to write a function `vreplicate :: n -> a -> Vec n a` which repeats a given element `n` times. `vreplicate` has to know *at runtime* how many copies of the value to make! However, the above type signature is invalid because Haskell maintains a separation between runtime values and compile-time types. Types belonging to the kind `Nat` can't be passed around at runtime. Enter *singleton values*.

```
data Natty n where
    Zy :: Natty Z
    Sy :: Natty n -> Natty (S n)
```

(This is more-or-less the code that the `singletons` library generates for you.) For a given (well-defined) `n` of kind `Nat`, there is precisely one (well-defined) value of type `Natty n`. Pattern-matching on a `Natty` tells you about its `n`. A `forall n. Natty n ->` quantifier tells you that `n` is used at runtime. So our `vreplicate` function will have a type of `Natty n -> a -> Vec n a`, with the `Natty n` as a runtime stand-in for `n`. (A real dependently typed language would not make you jump through such a hoop!)

As I mentioned, if you know the value of a `Natty` you know its `n`. We can additionally make information flow the other way, from types to values, using the following hacky type class:

```
class NATTY n where
    natty :: Natty n
instance NATTY Z where
    natty = Zy
instance NATTY n => NATTY (S n) where
    natty = Sy natty
```

A `NATTY n` dictionary is an implicit copy of `n`'s singleton `Natty`.

OK. The `Applicative` instance for `Vec` zips two vectors together, combining their contents pointwise.

```
vzip :: Vec n a -> Vec n b -> Vec n (a, b)
vzip VNil VNil = VNil
vzip (x :> xs) (y :> ys) = (x, y) :> vzip xs ys

vreplicate :: Natty n -> a -> Vec n a
vreplicate Zy _ = VNil
vreplicate (Sy n) x = x :> vreplicate n x

instance NATTY n => Applicative (Vec n) where
    pure = vreplicate natty
    fs <*> xs = fmap (uncurry ($)) (vzip fs xs)
```

And so we can lift a `Monoid` for `a`s into a `Monoid` for vectors of `a`. This is a standard trick to turn an `Applicative` into a `Monoid`.

```
instance Monoid a => Monoid (Vec n a) where
    mempty = pure mempty
    mappend = liftA2 mappend
```

The payoff: You can only `mappend` vectors whose lengths match. Compare this with the list `zip`, which truncates the longer of the two lists being zipped.

```
ghci> v1 `mappend` v2
"foobaz" :> ("barquux" :> VNil)

-- ┌       ┐     ┌        ┐     ┌           ┐
-- | "foo" |  +  | "baz"  |  =  | "foobar"  |
-- | "bar" |     | "quux" |     | "bazquux" |
-- └       ┘     └        ┘     └           ┘

ghci> v1 `mappend` v3
<interactive>:35:14: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘'Z’ with ‘'S 'Z’
      Expected type: Vec Two String
        Actual type: Vec One String
    • In the second argument of ‘mappend’, namely ‘v3’
      In the expression: v1 `mappend` v3
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = v1 `mappend` v3

-- ┌       ┐     ┌          ┐
-- | "foo" |  +  | "nabble" |  =  ?
-- | "bar" |     └          ┘
-- └       ┘
```

---

Now let's work with 2D matrices. The trick is to build them out of smaller reusable bits. A matrix is a vector of vectors, the type-level composition of two vectors.

```
newtype (f :.: g) a = Compose { getCompose :: f (g a) } deriving Show

type Mat n m = Vec n :.: Vec m
```

That is, `Mat n m a` is isomorphic to `Vec n (Vec m a)`.

Functoriality and applicativity are preserved through composition,

```
instance (Functor f, Functor g) => Functor (f :.: g) where
    fmap f = Compose . fmap (fmap f) . getCompose
instance (Applicative f, Applicative g) => Applicative (f :.: g) where
    pure = Compose . pure . pure
    Compose fgf <*> Compose fgx = Compose (liftA2 (<*>) fgf fgx)
```

and we can once more employ the standard trick to lift a `Monoid` into an `Applicative` of composed `Applicative`s.

```
instance (Monoid a, Applicative f, Applicative g) => Monoid ((f :.: g) a) where
    mempty = pure mempty
    mappend = liftA2 mappend
```

Now we get matrix addition for free!

```
m1 :: Mat Two Two String
m1 = Compose (v1 :> v2 :> VNil)
m2 :: Mat Two Two String
m2 = Compose (v2 :> v1 :> VNil)

ghci> m1 `mappend` m2
Compose {getCompose = ("foobaz" :> ("barquux" :> VNil)) :> (("bazfoo" :> ("quuxbar" :> VNil)) :> VNil)}

-- ┌              ┐     ┌              ┐     ┌                    ┐
-- | "foo" "bar"  |  +  | "baz" "quux" |  =  | "foobaz" "barquux" |
-- | "baz" "quux" |     | "foo" "bar"  |     | "bazfoo" "quuxbar" |
-- └              ┘     └              ┘     └                    ┘
```

There's another valid matrix `Monoid` (for square matrices, `newtype Square n = Square (Mat n n)`) which performs matrix multiplication, with the identity matrix as `mempty`. I won't show it here. You can figure it out yourself.

---

Lastly let's do addition of tensors, which are *n*-dimensional matrices. A tensor is a family of types indexed by a list of dimensions. That is, `Tensor` is a *function* from a list of dimensions to a type constructor `* -> *`. Adding a new dimension to the list adds a layer of `Vec`s.

```
type family Tensor (dims :: [Nat]) :: * -> * where
    Tensor '[d] = Vec d
    Tensor (d ': ds) = Vec d :.: Tensor ds
```

So, `Tensor '[One, Two, Three] a`, a one-by-two-by-three tensor, is `newtype`-isomorphic to `Vec One (Vec Two (Vec Three a))`.

Once again, by defining `Tensor` in terms of `Vec` and `:.:` we get the instance we need for free.

```
t1 :: Tensor '[Two, Two, Two] String
t1 = Compose (m1 :> m2 :> VNil)
t2 :: Tensor '[Two, Two, Two] String
t2 = Compose (m2 :> m1 :> VNil)

ghci> t1 `mappend` t2
Compose {getCompose = Compose {getCompose = ("foobaz" :> ("barquux" :> VNil)) :> (("bazfoo" :> ("quuxbar" :> VNil)) :> VNil)} :> (Compose {getCompose = ("bazfoo" :> ("quuxbar" :> VNil)) :> (("foobaz" :> ("barquux" :> VNil)) :> VNil)} :> VNil)}

-- i'm not going to try drawing that
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution :D !!! I will need a bit of time to understand it since I never used or even heard of kind polymorphism and promotions before... A new world has just opened up for me and I'm feeling like Alice ;-). Thanks you again!

Comment: @dmw64 I'll be happy to answer any questions you have :)