# Phantom Type w/ AnyVal?

Tags: scala, phantom-types

Given the following Phantom Type example in Haskell from [phadej](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28250226/409976):

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

newtype Distance a = Distance Double
  deriving (Num, Show)

data Kilometer
data Mile

marathonDistance :: Distance Kilometer
marathonDistance = Distance 42.195

distanceKmToMiles :: Distance Kilometer -> Distance Mile
distanceKmToMiles (Distance km) = Distance (0.621371 * km)

marathonDistanceInMiles :: Distance Mile
marathonDistanceInMiles = distanceKmToMiles marathonDistance
```

I attempted to translate that to Scala:

```
case class Distance[A](x: Double) extends AnyVal

case object Kilometer
case object Mile

def marathonDistance: Distance[Kilometer.type] = Distance[Kilometer.type](42.195)

def distanceKmToMiles(kilos: Distance[Kilometer.type]): Distance[Mile.type] = 
    Distance[Mile.type](kilos.x * 0.621371)

def marathonDistanceInMiles: Distance[Mile.type] = distanceKmToMiles( marathonDistance )
```

Assuming this Phantom Type implementation is valid in Scala, will this usage of `Distance` result in an allocation, i.e. use the heap, not the stack?

If it will allocate, what's the reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As is, your code shouldn't result in any allocation of a `Distance` class, because it doesn't do [any of the things that would cause it](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html#allocation-summary):

> 1. a value class is treated as another type.
> 2. a value class is assigned to an array.
> 3. doing runtime type tests, such as pattern matching.

It doesn't treat them as another type, there are no arrays, and no type tests.

In these examples, an instance of `Distance` would be allocated, boxed, and unboxed:

Type tests:

```
def d(dist: Distance[Mile.type]): Double = dist match {
    case Distance(x) if x > 0 => 1.0
    case Distance(x) => x
}
```

Treated as another type (generic A):

```
def identity[A](t: A): A = t
```

Arrays:

```
val dist = Distance[Meter.type](1.0)
val arr = Array[Distance[Meter.type]](dist)
```

The same is true whether the type parameter is there or not.